# A condition for a representation being self-dual

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products, characters

If $\pi$ is an irreducible representation of a group G such that the trivial representation occurs in $\pi \otimes \pi$ then does $\pi$ have to be self-dual, i.e $\pi \cong \pi^{*}$.$\\$

My attempt: We have $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle$=1 and also $\langle \chi_{\pi \otimes \pi},\mathbb{1} \rangle$=m (where m$\geq$1), from this to information we  get:
$$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} |\chi(g)|^{2}=1,\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G}( \chi(g))^{2}=m $$

If $\pi$ is self dual then $\chi_{\pi}(g)$=$\bar{\chi_{\pi}(g)}$ and then m must equals 1. So if we can get a $\pi$ such that trivial representation occurs more that once in $\pi \otimes \pi$ we are done and we can conclude that it is not self dual necessarily. But I can't find such an example and I don't know whether really we can find such an example or not. Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on a good way. So on the one hand $\langle\chi_{\pi\otimes\pi},1\rangle$ is the multiplicity of the trivial representation in $\pi\otimes\pi$. On the other hand, however, you also have $\chi_{\pi\otimes\pi} = \chi_{\pi}\chi_{\pi}$, and so $\langle\chi_{\pi\otimes\pi},1\rangle=\langle\chi_{\pi}\chi_{\pi},1\rangle=\ldots$ Can you continue from here leading you to an expression telling you whether $\pi$ and $\pi^{\ast}$ are isomorphic (remember $\langle\chi,\tau\psi\rangle=\langle\chi\overline{\tau},\psi\rangle$)?

Keeping in mind that the scalar product on characters is just a way of computing dimensions of homomorphism spaces, the above is a direct translation of the following representation theoretic content: You have $\pi\otimes\pi\cong\pi\otimes\pi^{\ast\ast}\cong\text{Hom}(\pi,\pi^{\ast})$. Now the invariants of the left hand side describe the trivial subrepresentations of $\pi\otimes\pi$, while the invariants on the right hand side are $\text{Hom}_G(\pi,\pi^{\ast})$.

Comment: I don't understand the following:$\pi\otimes\pi\cong\pi\otimes\pi^{\ast\ast}\cong\text{Hom}(\pi,\pi^{\ast})$. First that by  $\pi\otimes\pi$ do you mean the representation space $V \otimes V$

Comment: Also the following line:"Keeping in mind that the scalar product on characters is just a way of computing dimensions of homomorphism spaces".- By this do you mean that if $\pi_1$  and $\pi_2$ are two representations of G then $\langle \chi_{\pi_{1}}, \chi_{\pi_{2}} \rangle$=$Hom_{G}(\pi_{1},\pi_{2})$

Comment: Now if $\pi$ is irreducible then $\pi^{*}$ is also so. 
Then either $Hom_{G}(\pi,\pi^{*})$  is 0 or of dimension 1.

Comment: @Riju: 1. comment: yes, 2. comment: The scalar product is the _dimension_ of the homomorphism space. 3. comment: Yes, and now you almost have it!

Comment: See  if I compute dimension dim(V $\otimes V$) cannot be zero So, dim is 1 in the case where actually $\pi$ becomes selfdual. But in that case dim V=1 , that is $\pi$ is one dimensional  and it isnecessarily the trivial representation

Comment: @Riju: Wait, it's not about $\dim(V\otimes V)$, it's about $(V\otimes V)^G$, the subspace of _invariants_. That's the same as $\text{Hom}_G(1, V\otimes V)$, so it measures whether $V\otimes V$ contains the trivial representation. On the other hand, it's isomorphic to $\text{Hom}_G(V,V^{\ast})$, to it is $0$ or $1$ dimensional depending on whether $V$ is self-dual.

Comment: I think I get it.By subspace of invariants, you mean the fixed subspace right? You are telling  that the fixed subspace of $V \otimes V$ is isomorphic  $Hom_{G}(\pi,\pi^{*})$, now left hand side's dimension is more than or equal to 1, so the right side dim has to be 1 and in that case the trivial representation occurs only once in $\pi \otimes \pi$.

Comment: @Riju: Yes! Comparing the dimensions you see that $V$ is self dual if and only if $V\otimes V$ contains the trivial representation, and if that is the case, the multiplicity is in fact always equal to $1$.

Comment: can you please write the isomorphism.. I cannot show that the fixed subspace is isomorphic to $Hom_{G}(\pi, \pi^{*})$. Thanks!

Comment: The action of $g\in G$ on $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ is given by $g.\varphi = g\circ\varphi\circ g^{-1}$, so $\varphi$ is fixed precisely if $g\circ\varphi = \varphi\circ g$, i.e. if it is a $G$-homomorphism.

Comment: I haven't seen it.I will try and let u know. Thanks very much.