# Why contains the direct square of a representation in a 3D point group the trivial representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Which ways are there to show that in any [3D point group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_group) (a more or less complete list of those, including multiplication tables is [here](http://www.gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/character_tables/)) the tensor product of any irreducible representation (say $\Gamma_x$) with itself always decomposes to a sum of irreducible representations that contains the trivial representation ($\Gamma_0$)?:

$\operatorname{Hom}_G(\Gamma_0, \Gamma_x \otimes \Gamma_x) = \operatorname{Hom}_G(\Gamma_0 \otimes (\Gamma_x)^*, \Gamma_x)= \operatorname{Hom}_G((\Gamma_x)^*, \Gamma_x)=\operatorname{Hom}_G(\Gamma_x, \Gamma_x)$

Any ideas, explicitly from different approaches, are appreciated. 
This is an attempt to get some ideas how [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803235/why-contains-the-product-of-highest-dimensional-representation-with-dim-ne-1) could be approached. I think there might be some connection.

---

*) Point groups are (discrete) symmetry groups of Euclidean space which leave the origin fixed.

Comment: what is the "totally symmetric representation"?  If you mean the trivial representation, this is false.

Comment: @m_t_:Sorry for me its natural to imply point groups for groups. I have specified that. But your counter-example would be of interest

Comment: What does MathWorld mean by "all $1$s"? All the entries of a $1\times 1$ matrix are $1$? If so, why not just say "trivial representation," like literally almost every other source in existence?

Comment: (Sorry, most of my salt was directed at MathWorld.)

Comment: You have used the term "totally symmetric" for that long and never heard of the trivial representation? How is that possible? Any textbook on representation theory will use the term "trivial".

Comment: I used the ["Cotton"](http://hep.fcfm.buap.mx/ecursos/TTG/libros/Group%20Theory.pdf).

Comment: The statement is true iff $\Gamma_x$ is self-dual (assuming these are finite-dimensional representations).

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/nhJESK8) is the first occurrence of the thing and term in "the Cotton", afaik its never called differently in this source.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Is there any non-self-dual representation among the irreps of all the point groups (in particular 3D point groups)?

Comment: After taking a brief look in that book, it seems a tremendous shame that the author has decided to occasionally use terminology so different than what mathematicians use. The aim of the book is chemists, but some of those might at some point need to dive deeper into these things, in which case it would make sense to speak to a mathematician about it. And once that happens these people will spend some time being utterly confused due to an unnecessary difference in vocabolary.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I see what you mean, and agree.

Comment: Anyway, I am still not really sure what the significance of being a point group is in this context, though. And the link seems to be written mainly with chemists and similar in mind, so it becomes much too complicated to figure out which groups are examples.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Would you have a counter example, I mean an example for a non-self-dual representation?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212310/a-condition-for-a-representation-being-self-dual) is the backwards direction of your claim @TobiasKildetoft.

Comment: Now I see, of course all "our groups" (point groups) have exclusively self dual representations. These "point groups" are by the way "not many", so there is a famous (point) group theoretical result in chemistry called the "Jahn-Teller theorem" which was proven more or less by looking at each of the groups and checking some properties of the irreps. My project I am working on here goes in a similar direction, btw.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: might I please contact you otherwise (chat, email, ...) I have quite some questions in order to better understand how to communicate these things with a mathematician.

Comment: Sure, come to the chat. I am often there (and I am there right now).